# Add requires to default resources in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to add a require to the default resource for users in Puppet:

```
User { require => Mount['/home'] }
```

Using Puppet 0.25, I get the following error:

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at '+>'; expected '}' at /home/rpinson/puppetmaster/manifests/foo.pp:71 on node ip-bar.internal

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I assume line 71 is 'User {...'?  Also, '+>' appears to be supported in 0.25: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html.

Comment: Yes @KyleSmith, the syntax is supported in 0.25, but it doesn't seem to work unless it's applied in the case of an inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it might be easier to leverage a define resource instead of resource defaults.

```
define myuser (
  ... # you certainly need the rest of the user attribute.
) {
  user { $name:
    require => Mount['/home'],
    ... # and the rest of your attributes.
  }
}
```

If you declare myuser{ 'johndoe': }, it should also have mount as a requirement.

Comment: It doesn't work in this case. My use case is: I'm defining partitions and some servers have `/home` as a separate partition (using LVM). As a result, creating users (whatever they are) requires `/home` to be mounted on these servers. This is a general requirement, whatever resource triggers the user creation, so I can't use a wrapper for the user type.

Answer (score 0):

Use a resource collector:

```
User <| |> {
    require +> Mount['/home'],
}
```

This adds the requirement to all User instances, but also has a side-effect of realizing any virtual users.

As far is I remember, this is supported in 0.25.

Also, `+>` operator cannot be used in regular parameter definitions, only in overrides or collectors. Replace those with `=>`.